# Converting columns in panda dataframes to numerical values when exporting to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I've created a panda dataframe scraped from a website and have exported it into excel but the number values appear in text format in excel so wanted a quick way of converting all the number values into numbers that I can then analyse in excel automatically.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv
import os

def url_scraper(url):
    response=requests.get(url)
    html=response.text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    return soup

def first_inns_bowling_scorecard_scraper(url):
    soup=url_scraper(url)
    for divs in soup.find_all("div",{"id":"gp-inning-00"}):
        for bowling_div in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"scorecard-section bowling"}):
            table_headers=bowling_div.find_all("th")
            table_rows=bowling_div.find_all("tr")[1:]
    headers=[]
    for th in table_headers:
        headers.append(th.text)

    data = []
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [tr.text for tr in td]
        data.append(row)
    df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
    df.drop(df.columns[[1,9]], axis = 1,inplace=True)
    df.to_excel(r'C:\\Users\\nathang\\Downloads\\random.xlsx',index = None, header=True)
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\nathang\\Downloads')
    os.system("start EXCEL.EXE random.xlsx")
    return df

url="https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/19781/scorecard/1216418/afghanistan-vs-ireland-3rd-t20i-ireland-tour-of-india-2019-20"

first_inns_bowling_scorecard_scraper(url)
```

I've tried multiple different variations of the df.apply(pd.to_numeric) on individual columns, multiple columns, the whole dataset and so on but can't get anything to work for it. Ideally, I would like to just input the whole dataframe into it and if there is an error it ignores it.

Comment: I've sorted out a temporary way of handling this by using the following: df.iloc[:, -7:] = df.iloc[:, -7:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') but I wanted a more universal way so that I could ideally plug in any dataframe and it would sort out the text values that are numbers into floats or integers and ignore all the text values that aren't numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem.

```
a = "5"
int(a) = 5
row = [int(tr.text) for tr in td]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but this won't work as it's a mixture of both integers and text values.